# VBA: Transferring data from one worksheet to another with a "moving range"

Tags: vba, excel, inventory-management

I'm trying to create a dashboard of my inventory system. The dashboard will display Sales for the day (category 1), Purchases that need to be made (Category 2), Purchase Orders that are to be expected (Cateogry 3), and Work in Process (Category 4). For this question, I'm only going to focus on category 2, Purchases that need to be made.

I'm trying to transfer all the data from Worksheets("Purchasing") to the Dashboard under category 2. I'm trying to use named ranges to do this, because the range of each category will fluctuate as items are added/deleted. You can find a sample of the workbook that I'm working on [here](http://www.excelforum.com/showthread.php?t=1164923&p=4531672&highlight=#post4531672) - it's on excelforum.com.

The code below is what I have so far. It works to a degree, but the Range("PurchaseStart"), which is Cell $A$8, starts at A:1. I don't know how to only select the named range that I'm looking for. I added "End #" statements at the end of each row to signify a cutoff and hope to trick excel into only selecting the range of the particular category.

```
Option Explicit

Sub purchPull()

Dim Dashboard As Worksheet
Dim Purchasing As Worksheet
Dim PM As Range, D As Range, Rng As Range
Dim purchName As Range

Set Purchasing = Worksheets("Purchasing")
Set Dashboard = Worksheets("Dashboard")


' Go through each Item in Purchasing and check to see if it's anywhere      within the named range "PurchaseStart"
' In this case it should be "A8:A9" - as there is nothing in the dasboard yet
For Each PM In Purchasing.Range(Purchasing.Cells(1, 1),     Purchasing.Cells(Purchasing.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    With Dashboard.Range("PurchaseStart",   Dashboard.Cells(Dashboard.Rows.Count, 1))
    Set Rng = .Find(What:=PM.Offset(0, 1), _
        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        ' Do nothing, as we don't want duplicates
    Else
        ' From the start of the named range, transfer data over - THIS IS THE PROBLEM AREA
        With Dashboard.Range("PurchaseStart", Dashboard.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)).End(xlUp)
            .Offset(1, 1) = PM.Offset(0, 0) ' Order Number
            .Offset(1, 2) = PM.Offset(0, 1) ' SKU
            .Offset(1, 3) = PM.Offset(0, 3) ' Qty
            .Offset(1, 4) = PM.Offset(0, 4) ' Date
        End With
    End If
End With
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along the lines of: 
(This assumes that the beginning of each data section has some header in place, ie "Need to be made" and then below that header is where the data for that section goes):

```
Sub findDataStartRow()
Dim f as Range, dataStartRange as Range

Set f = Columns(1).Find(what:="Need to be made", lookat:xlWhole)
If Not f is Nothing Then
    dataStartRange = Cells(f.row + 1, 1) 'Do stuff with this range... maybe insert rows below it to start data
Else: Msgbox("Not found")
    Exit Sub
End if
End Sub
```

Do similar for each section. This way, no matter where the header goes (and therefore the beginning of where the data should be placed), you'll always have a named range of the location right below the header.
Alternatively, if you want to add the data to the end of the section, just find the header for the section below where you want the data to be and set the `dataStartRange = Cells(f.row - 1, 1)` after modifying the `.Find` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I think it's a pretty good way of handling the problem, but if anyone can think of a better way, I'd love to hear it. Thanks for the help everyone.

```
Option Explicit

Sub purchPull()

Dim Dashboard As Worksheet
Dim Purchasing As Worksheet
Dim PM As Range, D As Range, Rng As Range
Dim purchName As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim firstRow As Long

Set Purchasing = Worksheets("Purchasing")
Set Dashboard = Worksheets("Dashboard")

' first row of named range "PurchaseStart"
firstRow = Dashboard.Range("PurchaseStart").Row +     Dashboard.Range("PurchaseStart").Rows.Count



' Go through each Item in Purchasing and check to see if it's anywhere within the named range "PurchaseStart"
With Purchasing
For Each PM In Purchasing.Range(Purchasing.Cells(2, 1), Purchasing.Cells(Purchasing.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    With Dashboard.Range("PurchaseStart", Dashboard.Cells(Dashboard.Rows.Count, 1))
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=PM.Offset(0, 0), _
            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            ' Do nothing, as we don't want duplicates
        Else      
            ' Identify the last row within the named range "PurchaseStart"
            lastRow = Dashboard.Range("PurchaseStart").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
            ' Transfer the data over
            With Dashboard.Cells(lastRow, 1).End(xlUp)
                .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
                .Offset(1, 0) = PM.Offset(0, 0)  ' Order Number
                .Offset(1, 1) = PM.Offset(0, 1) ' SKU
                .Offset(1, 2) = PM.Offset(0, 2) ' Qty
                .Offset(1, 3) = PM.Offset(0, 3) ' Date
            End With
        End If
    End With
Next
End With

End Sub
```